# Electronic pan/tilt camera

Tags: sensor, interface, camera, imageprocessing, ideas

Is it possible to conceive of a system that would use a stationary camera with a fish-eye lens to effectively provide the same images as a camera that was actually panning and tilting.

Comment: Yes, but you pay for it in resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The results would be pretty awful.  The distortion from a fish eye lens would result in images that look ridiculous compared to image stitching.  Although your results of the stitched images vary based on the quality of your lens, all fisheye images I've ever seen result in vertical lines looking bowed.

http://wiki.panotools.org/Fisheyes

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Couldn't the bowing and distortion be corrected in software?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but it seems plausible that you could do some correction in software.  Here's something that the google told me about: http://fisheyelensreview.com/defishing-software/top-3-defishing-software-programs-to-easily-defish-your-images/

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of recalculating the image projection, and has been done in software, so the short answer is yes - it's possible. Whether it's worth it would require some more knowledge.

An example is [using Hugin to remap fisheye images](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/enfuse-360/en.shtml).

Comment: It's instructive to look at the cost of pixels on camera versus the cost of lenses & motors. For some applications like robot situational awareness it's a good tradeoff.